# Quality of murmur3f and xxhash different variations

Tags: hash, murmurhash

From https://github.com/rurban/smhasher/,
it seems that murmur3f and xxhash function (except xxh3) have the same quality, with respect that both functions return "uniform" results across different of workload.

Are there any other results regarding uniformarty to different real-world workload? (We assume the it is not a "deliviret" from an attacker).

Comment: I have to admit I don't get what you are asking about. Can you elaborate? What exactly do you want to find out in this question?

Comment: @tansy Are there any "score" method to compare between xxhash128 and murmur3F, to decide who is a "better" uniform function